# Creating moulds to store fragile or important objects

Tags: storage

Sometimes when I buy stuff they come in a box that has a black foam inside it. This foam has cut outs to hold that object. Its quite interesting.

I have some fragile and valuable objects that I want to store in small wooden or plastic boxes but, I think it is important that they be stored inside such foam cut outs or something else that is soft and is designed to store these objects.

The question is, how can this be achieved at home? I could buy black foam sheets and cut them out but they won't have the correct 3D cut out to hold the fragile precious object. I could use silicon rubber mould that I believe (not sure) is a liquid that becomes solid after being poured and takes shape of the object that is inside it.

What would be the correct way to create some sort of mould or cut out that is soft and be used inside the box (both above and below the object) when these fragile precious objects are stored in a box?

Comment: Pre cubed foam. https://www.easyfoam.co.uk/pre-cubed-foam.php - Worked at a place that packaged in this stuff; fun to play with. And probably a lot more expensive than newspaper. It's cut into ~1" squares vertically and laterally but still kinda stuck . *You* pull out chunks until its the shape you want. Making that stuff at home? Yeah no.

Comment: If the thing's 10 grand, then you can drop 500 bucks on a bespoke(d) Pelican. The rest of us use cardboard boxes and newspaper. If it isn't getting shipped, it's fine. And if it isn't an R&D company where *presentation is everything*, does it really have to be that cool?

Comment: pop some popcorn and use it to pack the item

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about home improvement

Comment: Unless you're trying to ensure survival in an earthquake (which gets dubious, depending how much building drops on the box) there's no need for fancy packing for items that are not being subjected to shipping abuse. Things stored at home or even transported by the owner in a car, not UPS/FedEx/USMail on conveyors and trucks have no need for that level of fuss. But if you want to buy a laser scanner and a CNC hot wire foam cutter, be my guest.

Comment: I have lot of stuff lying on shelves, it looks ugly. A lot of these things are in the shed shelves. I need to put them away into containers but am interested in creating something that is moulded to their shape. Since it is about reducing clutter, it can be classified as home improvement.

Comment: *How to make per cubed foam?*  **hot wire foam cutter** and a mask rated for organic vapors... yuck. - Been putting xmas ornaments in paper and CB boxes for +40y. The only ones that ever break are the ones I put w/o paper and just rely on the other's paper. If you got figurines with swords sticking up then IDKWTTY.

Answer (score 7):

Door and Window spray foams are calibrated to not exert much pressure in confined spaces.

- Spray a base layer of foam into a box, and let the foam cure.
- Spray an addition layer to half the item height in the box, wrap the item in cellophane plastic wrap, bed the isolated item in the foam, and let the foam cure.
- Clean up the plastic, apply additional plastic on top of the items and lay a debonding layer of plastic across the whole box so that the next foam doesn't bond to the old foam, fill the box the to its top with spray foam, install the top half of the box, and let the foam cure.
- Disassemble everything and clean up any unwanted plastic.

Comment: Be sure to get something labeled "non-expanding" or it may damage your stuff